# Ambiguity in pow(x,y,z) and x**y%z speed in python 3. Which one is efficient?

Tags: python-3.x, numbers, long-integer, pow, processing-efficiency

results are not as expected. pow(x,y,z) must be efficient, but the results altered. why?

[image]

```
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit("pow(2505626,1520321,2700643)"))
output:3.700144177302718
print(timeit.timeit("pow(2505626,1520321,2700643)",number=1000000))
output:4.591832527890801
print(timeit.timeit("2505626**1520321%2700643",number=1000000))
output:0.014752348884940147
```

Comment: Don't ask about images of code. Copy the code to the question itself.

Comment: You're using timeit with only one execution and you're expecting an accurate result ?

Comment: @ArtOfCode image is to show the output accurately.

Comment: @alfasin I have done it hundred times. Explain to me, why the efficiency is altered?

Comment: You can have images in _support_ of your post, but **all** the relevant code and output **must** be copied directly into your post.

Comment: @alfasin ArtOfCode yeah I have edited it with the code. Please let me know the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed `pow()` doesn't have good performance on integers (in the three argument form). See the function's docstring:

code:

```
def pow(*args, **kwargs): # real signature unknown
    """
    Equivalent to x**y (with two arguments) or x**y % z (with three arguments)

    Some types, such as ints, are able to use a more efficient algorithm when
    invoked using the three argument form.
    """
    pass
```